# Loop formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     NSInteger n = 5;
     NSInteger nFactorial = n;
     while (n > 1) {
         nFactorial = nFactorial * --n;
     }
     NSLog(@"The factorial of %ld is %ld", (long)n, (long)nFactorial);
     return YES;
 }
```

For this code, why does nFactorial have to be initialized to n?  Why can't the code just use n in all the places that have nFactorial in it?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to make the first loop have a right result.
2. nFactorial = nFactorial * --n ,'--'has a higher priority.

if use `n` replaces `nFactorial`, the value of the second `nFactorial` is not our exception.